# Is there a way to filter out filenames from vim's "oldfiles", perhaps using a pattern?

Tags: vim, git, regex, vi

I use vim's `:browse oldfiles` a lot to edit files I've recently worked with. However, there are some files, such as git's auto-generated COMMIT_EDITMSG, which clutter that list and which I never need to edit explicitly. Is there a way to filter filenames out from being displayed (or, better) saved in that list, perhaps using a regex or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the (quick) function below to filter out commit messages from the `v:oldfiles` variable before the actual browsing:

```
function! CleanBrowse()
    call filter(v:oldfiles, 'v:val !~ "COMMIT_EDITMSG"')
    browse :oldfiles
endfunction
nnoremap <F6> :call CleanBrowse()<CR>
```

It doesn't change the content of your `~/.viminfo` so it seems to be relatively safe.

More information:

```
:h :oldfiles
:h v:oldfiles
:h list-functions
:h filter()
:h !~
```

I don't know of a way to decide what should and what shouldn't be saved in `~/.viminfo` but I would be curious to learn.

Comment: That works. Unfortunately it doesn't affect the filelist saved, which means (in my case for example) only 19 entries are shown rather than 20, once COMMIT_EDITMSG is filtered out. But it does clean up the list, thanks.

Comment: You could easily remove the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` lines from your `~/.viminfo` with something like `:g/COMMIT_EDITMSG/d` but `v:oldfiles` is defined at startup so you would need to restart Vim each time you do that cleanup.